# What's better for the fan's health? OFF and ON or Low - High Speed?

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan

I wonder what is better for fan's health.

E.g. fans in my laptop. I can't change their speed by % (0-100%).

Setting 0% is like turning them off.

And I just don't know what would be best for them and what's gonna hurt them most.

So

Better to have fans running all the time with e.g. 30% speed and speed up when CPU usage increases?

Or

Is it better to have them turned off and start up only when CPU usage increases and when it is really needed.

And this question is only about fan's health. Not CPU's or GPU's.

Comment: Does it matter? The internal fan controller is there for a reason... it's likely something else will fail first, before the fans give out.

Comment: @spikey_richie I disagree - there are no other moving parts in a laptop with SSD, making the fan one of the most likely things to fail in many environments.

Comment: @Davidgo you assume only mechanical items stop working...

Comment: @spikey_richie - not so. I assert  that mechanical parts have a higher failure rate then electrical ones. That's why SSDs are an order of magnitude more reliable then spinning disks, why RAID (note the R) is a thing.  I am involved in maintaining  about 100 systems - so that is my data pool.  Spinning things, capacitors, things frequently plugged and unplugged break more often then motherboards, CPUs, RAM - although they do break as well). Relatedly, what parts in cars are  part of routine services and why are TVs more reliable then washing machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fan is a moving mechanical part and *will* eventually break over time.  The question is whether it will wear out quickly, or it will last for decades?

In my experience, computer fans tend to last for very long periods of time and rarely fail.  From what I have seen, fans that fail tend to be kept in very dusty environments.  Dust gets inside the fans spindle, causing it to spin poorly and the added friction eventually wears out to electric motor.

The good news is that computer fans are cheap.  Heck, you can get them for free from people who are discarding old computers.  You dont need to buy expensive fans with lights in them.  You dont need to buy name brand fans that cost a lot for some unknown reason.  A fan is a fan.

With all that information in mind, I would recommend letting your fans run.  That is what they are designed to do and thats why they are in your computer.  On the off chance that a fan were to fail, just replace it.

Comment: Seconded, if you're avoiding dust, then the next biggest source of wear is going to be spinning up the fans from a stopped state, especially if the fan uses cheap bearings.